# Migrating Windows to SSD

Tags: windows, windows-7, ssd

I've been following the various guides online for migrating to an SSD but I just can't seem to  get my partition to shrink to a small enough size. I've run every defrag option in defraggler multiple times, and I've run the Windows 7 defragmentation tool plenty of times too, but the Windows disk manager won't shrink my partition any smaller than 1277.8 GB. I only have 128 GB of data on this disk, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Defraggler's graphical view of the disk blocks shows a long sequence contiguous block of used space, and then all empty space. Still, the disk management tool won't let me shrink the partition any further.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: I think you might have posted this to the wrong site by accident.

Comment: I think the deframentation should be done from an external OS,loaded from a USB or CD/DVD. Also to reduce the partition size there are many specialized tools from Acronis, Paragon,Minitool .... or just even Linux+gparted or disks

Answer (score 1):

You should use Microsoft's Imaging system imagex to capture an image, and apply that image to the new SSD. ImageX is a filesystem based imaging system, not a sector based imaging system. You'd boot to a winpe disk, capture the image to a USB drive or network share or external, or whatever, and apply the image. Again, since ImageX is a file systembased imaging sysytem and not a sector based imaging system you wont have to worry about the partition size or anything.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753

To copy: `imagex /capture d: d:\imaging\data.wim "Drive D" /verify`

To apply: `imagex /apply d:\imaging\data.wim 1 /verify`

Comment: I thought ImageX was the tool used by the system imager, which I already tried. It wouldn't restore to the SSD, and when I looked up the error I received online, the implication seemed that I still had to shrink the partition to fit within the SSD size. Is this not the case?

Comment: clean the disk and create an active partition

Comment: I'll try the command-line version then, thanks. Do I need to reboot into the recovery console to copy and/or apply imagex?  Edit: never mind, didn't realize it's an iso.

Comment: Quite an ordeal still. Had to generate a Windows PE boot CD containing the imagex program, then generate the image from the original disk. I wrote the image to the SSD and fixed the booting issues (missing mbr, etc.), and now it boots, but the user desktops don't load. It just sits there on a blue background after successful login. Also, I had biometric software installed which showed certain icons on the login screen, and those are gone as well and biometrics doesn't work for login. Not sure what's going on now. Any thoughts?

Comment: it's booting to the same PC?

Comment: Yes, same hardware, just swapped a 2TB HDD for a 240GB SSD. System image is around 100GB. I'm trying a full xcopy from the original disk to the SSD over the imagex restored files, just in case some important files were missed. Still in process.

Comment: No dice on the xcopy. Trying to logon fails immediately with the error, "The User Profile Service service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded." I suppose I'll just try the imagex again.

Comment: Same thing happened with the second imagex. No biometrics at login, and trying to login spends minutes at the "Preparing your desktop" screen and brings up a dialog "You must restart your computer to apply these changes". After restart, login goes to a blank blue screen and just sits there.

Comment: Ok this is bizarre. The HDD uses 116GB, but the imagex captured image is only 70GB. Why would they differ so much in size? I didn't use any compression options when capturing the image.

Comment: ImageX does that. The image file is seldom as large as the space being used. because it ignores certain things like the recycling bin and other places it doesn't need.

Comment: Well, I don't know what else to do at this point. I suppose I'll just have to reinstall everything from scratch. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use another partitioning software, I recommend using [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com)

Burn the ISO file and boot from the CD.

Answer (score 0):

On a couple of occasions I've defragged a disk and found there's 'unmovable' data, even when booting from a CD or USB. In almost every case these have been USN journal files.

Try booting from a BartPE disk and run mydefrag and see if you have small blocks showing red, if they are USNJrnl files, try deleteing them as detailed on the mydefrag website: http://www.mydefrag.com/VolumeActions-DeleteJournal.html